# Sonata Admin - DISTINCT in datagrid filter

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to have optional filter where user can select distinct values (emails). Is there a possibility to create custom query builder?

```
$datagridMapper->add(
     'distinctRecords',
     'doctrine_orm_callback',
     [
          'callback' => function ($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
               if (!$value['value']) {
                   return;
               } else {
               // WHAT TO ADD HERE ???
               }
          }
     ],
     'choice',
     [
        'choices' => [
            'Yes' => true,
            'No' => false
         ],
         'expanded' => false,
         'multiple' => false
    ]
);
```